# Two way binding inside a separate controller not working with angular-wizard

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to incorporate this cool wizard controller into my project:

http://mgonto.github.io/angular-wizard/

Unfortunately, I can't get two-way binding to work outside of the `<section>` attribute:

http://plnkr.co/edit/N2lFrBRmRqPkHhUBfn3I?p=preview

There are two controllers; WizardCtrl and TextCtrl. The WizardCtrl is defined at the `<html>` tag, and the TextCtrl is declared at the first `<div>`. Here's the code in the head that makes the wizard work:

```
var app = angular.module('wizard-sample', ['mgo-angular-wizard']);

app.controller('WizardCtrl', function($scope, WizardHandler) {
  $scope.finished = function() {
    alert("Wizard finished :)");
  }

  $scope.logStep = function() {
    console.log("Step continued");
  }

  $scope.goBack = function() {
    WizardHandler.wizard().goTo(0);
  }
});

app.controller('TextCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

Anyone know what's going wrong here? Here's my latest code, any help would be really appreciated:

http://plnkr.co/edit/e7r4yskYHdyGTyB2jYcF?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few changes are required for your script,
you have to do this:

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, WizardHandler) {
        $scope.data = {};
      });

<input type="text" ng-model="data.dynamicText" placeholder="Write Something" />

 <p>{{data.dynamicText}}</p>
```

live sample : http://plnkr.co/edit/vxcIlITfYMPuml2LqJCj?p=preview